# Usenet: should good questions be ported to StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Since about 2005 I’ve posted on Usenet, in [comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.postscript/). Some of these posts have been ‘small’ questions or answers, some have been more substantial (e.g., the two linked from [Bézier approximation of Archimedes spiral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179000/b%c3%a9zier-approximation-of-archimedes-spiral/4810490#4810490)).

As has been much reported elsewhere, Google Groups is soon to cease providing write access to UseNet, and it is not implausible to believe that read access will later be lost.

**Should I port across updated versions of the questions of durable interest?** That wouldn’t quite be copy-paste, because errors will be fixed, answers given, etc., but it would not be fundamentally new tellings of new questions. Some of these might belong in [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/), some in [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), some elsewhere including [Stack Overflow—PostScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postscript) (which is not Stack Exchange).

What would be best for Stack Exchange, what would be best for its readers?

A similar question has been asked at [comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.postscript/c/dy_Ky9EQlFs).

Answer (score 4):

There is no "should" :) But you are definitely encouraged to post any relevant Q&A you want to (verbatim, if you have the rights) on the appropriate site on the network.

This applies to all Q&As found anywhere online, really. Just be sure it's not a duplicate of an existing question (I believe the chances of that might be quite high on StackOverflow), and that it follows all other guidelines stipulated in the site's Help Center.

This is essentially (and for all intents and purposes) not different from bumping into questions spontaneously.

Also note that your Q&As will here be released under a [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license (and that "*you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content*", see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) for more).

Comment: Done, twice so far: [How approximate {X,Y} functions as Bézier cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862965/), and [PostScript circles: how accurate, how improve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855798/).

Answer (score 3):

Proposed answer.

- For questions of durable interest, so for questions which might help others search here, yes.
- For questions narrowly about PostScript, not on StackExchange, maybe on StackOverflow.
- For matters unlikely to be of interest to others again, not at all.

For any that are ported across, the version on Stack* should link to the comp.lang.postscript original, and, if possible, that should link back.

Answer (score -1):

I'd consider a few things. Very little on internet is 'truly' dead - as long as it's mirrored somewhere

- internet archive backups of the original sources seem useful
- they need to respect the 'format' of SE - so porting would be a question and answer pair *inspired* by the discussion thread rather than a simple direct copy over
- in general the person posting them is likely to need to maintain them at least on the medium term.

I do feel like it would be in line with preserving knowledge for the commons, which seems very much in line with what the community aims for.

Comment: "Very little on internet is 'truly' dead" The better you prepare for it dying the less likely you are going to need it. For those situations where you don't prepare, you're likely going to need it and then you're too late. Wouldn't be the first time a Google product vanishes just about completely.

Comment: Precisely, or someone will back it up. And it could be you 

Comment: "*Very little on internet is 'truly' dead - as long as it's mirrored somewhere*" yet also *finding* that mirror can prove challenging. Moreover, any links to the original can rot. Recent example from SO where a well-known and seemingly well-established coding site "died" yet the domain was grabbed by a gambling place for essentially free exposure: ["DreaminCode" links redirect to a gambling site. How can we handle posts that link to this domain?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427348). Sure, the content is *somewhere*. It's not exactly as accessible as before, though.

Comment: Hence the suggestion of also making a WBM content backup

Comment: “likely to need to maintain them”: if you mean for the initial conversation, then sure. If you meant long after that, please say what and why.

Comment: Hence medium term - least initially someone might comment for clarification. I've a single SO answer that relies on a external link, which I check annually or so for staleness when reminded.